# Can I use sed to manipulate a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, replace, sed

In my program, I would like to first get the user input, and insert a `\` before each `/`
so I write this, but it doesn't work.

```
echo "input a website"
read website

sed '/\//i\/' $website
```

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Try this:

```
website=$(sed 's|/|\\/|g' <<< $website)
```

Bash actually supports this sort of replacement [natively](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

`${parameter/pattern/string}` — replace the first match of `pattern` with `string`.
`${parameter//pattern/string}` — replace all matches of `pattern` with `string`.

Therefore you can do:

```
website=${website////\\/}
```

Explanation:

```
website=${website // / / \\/}
                  ^  ^ ^  ^
                  |  | |  |
                  |  | |  string, '\' needs to be backslashed
                  |  | delimiter
                  |  pattern
                  replace globally
```

Comment: the native version did not work for me with large variable content `command to long:`

Comment: Eugene, thank you so much for the breakdown of which part of sed does what. That was the most clear explanation I've seen to-date.

Comment: Upvoted for incredible detail, esp. `'\' needs to be backslashed`

Answer (score 24):

```
echo $website | sed 's/\//\\\//g'
```

or, for better readability:

```
echo $website | sed 's|/|\\/|g'
```

Comment: it works well as well .Would you mind explain this 's/\//\\\//g'
 and this 's|/|\\/|g'??

Comment: `searchreplacecommand|source|target|global(all matches)` where you can use any character as separator (`|`). traditionally `/` is used for a separator

Comment: however when i use " " and variable . it doesn't insert anything. Can you figure out the reason? thanks

Comment: This does not save the modified contents back into the variable

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Parameter-Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to replace sub-strings in variable.
For example:

```
website="https://stackoverflow.com/a/58899829/658497"
echo "${website//\//\\/}"
```

> https:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/a\/58899829\/658497