# Removing colors from output

Tags: bash, unix, colors, console, ansi-escape

I have some script that produces output with colors and I need to remove the ANSI codes.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec > >(tee log)   # redirect the output to a file but keep it on stdout
exec 2>&1

./somescript
```

The output is (in log file):

```
java (pid  12321) is running...@[60G[@[0;32m  OK  @[0;39m]
```

I didn't know how to put the ESC character here, so I put `@` in its place.

I changed the script into:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec > >(tee log)   # redirect the output to a file but keep it on stdout
exec 2>&1

./somescript | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```

But now it gives me (in log file):

```
java (pid  12321) is running...@[60G[  OK  ]
```

How can I also remove this '`@[60G`?

Maybe there is a way to completely disable coloring for the entire script?

Comment: For node/npm, you can use `strip-ansi`: https://github.com/chalk/strip-ansi.

Comment: This was previously asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-to-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell-sc/6534712#6534712

Answer (score 252):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), the `[m|K]` in the `sed` command you're using is specifically designed to handle `m` (the color command) and `K` (the "erase part of line" command). Your script is trying to set absolute cursor position to 60 (`^[[60G`) to get all the OKs in a line, which your `sed` line doesn't cover.

(Properly, `[m|K]` should probably be `(m|K)` or `[mK]`, because you're not trying to match a pipe character. But that's not important right now.)

If you switch that final match in your command to `[mGK]` or `(m|G|K)`, you should be able to catch that extra control sequence.

```
./somescript | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}(;[0-9]{1,2};?)?)?[mGK]//g"
```

Comment: BSD/OSX users: We usually don't have the -r option to sed. `brew install gnu-sed` will install a capable version. Run with `gsed`.

Comment: If I do `echo "$(tput setaf 1)foo$(tput sgr0) bar" | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" | cat -A` , I get : `foo^O bar$` So I guess some characters are not correctly removed, right ? Do you know how to correct ?

Comment: @edi9999 As far as I can tell, the difference there is that color settings beyond 16 colors (as `setaf` supports) require more parameters than just two; my regex supports two. Changing the first `?` out for `*` should help. Handling `sgr0` is possible but based on a search it likely grows outside the scope of this hacky regex-based answer.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer which adds a `sed` to the pipe to strip the "shift in" character

Comment: This doesn't work reliably as there can be a third value (ala `[38;5;45m`). This alternative answer works https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55547/168277

Comment: What about removing output formatting control characters ?
For example, running `maestro-ng status > file.txt` will have a lot of styling special characters. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Using the script I wasn't able to remove the coloring in here `\u001b[0;1;34mVARIABLE\u001b[0;m"`

Comment: This does not work for me. It is showing as a different color of grey.

Comment: Adding this as `alias decolorize='sed -r "s/\\x1B\\[([0-9]{1,3}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g"'` to your bashrc creates a very nice utility that can be used both as `command | decolorize` and as `decolorize file.log`.

Comment: More correct form is `sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}(;[0-9]{1,3})*)?[mGK]//g"`, because there can be more terms and they can be also 3 digits long. E.g. `\e[38;5;123m` or even `\e[38;5;123;48;5;246m`.

Comment: For @FERCSl's update, note both `{1,3}` in both expressions, and `*` instead of `?` for the inner group. Valid coloring: `echo -e '\x1b[38;5;246;03mcolor me timbers'` matched by @FERcsl, but not original.

Answer (score 91):

IMHO, most of these answers try too hard to restrict what is inside the escape code. As a result, they end up missing common codes like `[38;5;60m` (foreground ANSI color 60 from 256-color mode).

They also require the `-r` option which enables [GNU extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html). These are not required; they just make the regex read better.

Here is a simpler answer that handles the 256-color escapes and works on systems with non-GNU `sed`:

```
./somescript | sed 's/\x1B\[[0-9;]\{1,\}[A-Za-z]//g'
```

This will catch anything that starts with `[`, has any number of decimals and semicolons, and ends with a letter. This should catch any of the [common ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences).

For funsies, here's a larger and more general (but minimally tested) solution for [all conceivable ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Escape_sequences):

```
./somescript | sed 's/\x1B[@A-Z\\\]^_]\|\x1B\[[0-9:;<=>?]*[-!"#$%&'"'"'()*+,.\/]*[][\\@A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]//g'
```

(and if you have @edi9999's SI problem, add  `| sed "s/\x0f//g"` to the end; this works for [any control char](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_(ASCII_and_derivatives)) by replacing `0f` with the hex of the undesired char)

Comment: This one worked nicely to string colour out of Azure az cli prettified output.

Comment: Fixed @elig. Turns out it had a number of issues, starting with some editor replacing all my dashes with weird unicode versions, but also a bunch of improper escaping - `|` in sed, `]` inside a character class in sed, and `'` in a single-quoted bash string. It is now working for me for a very basic test case.

Comment: I think there might be an error with the first regex - `\+` will make the plus sign a literal, but I think it is mean to be an "at least one" modifier of the previous range.

Comment: @halfer, when using `sed` without the `-r` option, `+` is treated as a literal and `\+` is treated as a modifier, in contradiction to most modern usage.

Comment: @meustrus: ah right, thanks. Out of interest, is this behaviour at the shell level or at the Sed level? It sounds like you're describing something in Sed, which I agree is an unexpected syntax!

Comment: So actually, I was wrong. I think `\+` worked on Mac, but it's not part of [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02). In the interest of maximum correctness and portability, I've changed `\+` to `\{1,\}`.

To answer your new question, this behavior is specific to `sed`, not your shell.

Comment: These work on macos if you use `gsed` instead of `sed`.

Comment: This is my preferred answer, but for my use case there was a small problem, the output I was processing contained `^[[m` which was not being caught. Resolved by amending like so `./somescript | sed 's/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[A-Za-z]//g'`

Comment: This solution did not work for me. It left some escape codes that weren't visible from the terminal inside a text file. (generated by a `git diff`) The accepted answer worked.

Answer (score 72):

I came across `ansi2txt` tool from `colorized-logs` package in Debian. The tool drops ANSI control codes from STDIN.

Usage example:

```
./somescript | ansi2txt
```

Source code http://github.com/kilobyte/colorized-logs

Comment: The package 'colorized-logs' exists in Ubuntu's standard repository, which makes the installation of this tool very easy with: 'sudo apt install colorized-logs'.

It works great and I have yet to find a problem with it.  This should be the official answer.

Comment: Likewise for AUR folks: aur/colorized-logs

Comment: From the manual page: All  ANSI  codes are simply ignored, including all cursor positioning ones.

This package removes all colorized parts, e.g. timestamp which makes it pretty useless.

Comment: It seems that one can also install with `pip install --user ansi2txt` or with `pip install ansi2txt`.

Answer (score 50):

I couldn't get decent results from any of the other answers, but the following worked for me:

```
somescript | sed -r "s/[[:cntrl:]]\[[0-9]{1,3}m//g"
```

If I only removed the control char "^[", it left the rest of the color data, e.g., "33m".  Including the color code and "m" did the trick.  I'm puzzled with s/\x1B//g doesn't work because \x1B[31m certainly works with echo.

Comment: On OSX (BSD sed), use `-E` instead of `-r` for extended regex.
More could be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131940)

Comment: i had to replace `{1,3}` to `{,3}` (otherwise it was still skipping some controls), thanks for your solution!

Comment: Since they might be multiple numbers separated with semi-colons (for background color, bold, italic, etc...). This command worked for me: `sed -r "s/[[:cntrl:]]\[([0-9]{1,3};)*[0-9]{1,3}m//g"`

Comment: This one (of the many I tested) worked with Ansible output that had been run with unbuffer.

Comment: for those that want to view logs that contain color codes using the less command this worked for me on ubuntu.

`cat errors.log | sed -r "s/[[:cntrl:]]\[[0-9]{1,3}m//g" | tee errors-copy.log | less errors-copy.log`

Comment: This does not catch all escape codes for me unlike the excepted answer.

Answer (score 46):

For Mac OSX or BSD use

```
./somescript | sed $'s,\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g'
```

Comment: Strange, this one worked fine for debian but other above didn't.

Comment: This one partially worked. However, if I open a file in excel, I'm still seeing this special character "?" at the end of each line.

Comment: @doudy_05 Try to pass `-E` flag for sed to enable extended regexp.

Comment: Works for `Raspbian` (partly, I can see `^M`) and `MacOs Big Sur` (completely). Thanks, saved my time.

Comment: This one works for Busybox (Asus router) while others don't.

Answer (score 33):

The regular expression below will miss some [ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) sequences, as well as 3 digit colors. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/Qjtopi/1) and [Fix](https://regex101.com/r/wYygBw/1) on regex101.com.

Use this instead:

```
./somescript | sed -r 's/\x1B\[(;?[0-9]{1,3})+[mGK]//g'
```

---

I also had the problem that sometimes, the SI character appeared.

It happened for example with this input : `echo "$(tput setaf 1)foo$(tput sgr0) bar"`

Here's a way to also strip the SI character (shift in) (0x0f)

```
./somescript | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" | sed "s/\x0f//g"
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer receives so little credit. This is the only one working for me...

Comment: This one is close to working, but it misses the three digit case and sequences of color codes like: `U+001B[38;2;128;128;128m`. See the unfound colors at https://regex101.com/r/Qjtopi/1. Regex that works for me can be found at https://regex101.com/r/wYygBw/1

Answer (score 12):

There's also a dedicated tool to handle ANSI escape sequences: [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.html).  Use the default `--text` output format to strip all ANSI escape sequences (note: not just coloring).

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6534712

Comment: in case you like to build it yourself, the source is at https://gitlab.com/saalen/ansifilter/

Comment: `brew install ansifilter`

Answer (score 11):

Much simpler function in pure Bash to filter-out common ANSI codes from a text stream:

```
# Strips common ANSI codes from a text stream

shopt -s extglob # Enable Bash Extended Globbing expressions
ansi_filter() {
  local line
  local IFS=
  while read -r line || [[ "$line" ]]; do
    printf '%s\n' "${line//$'\e'[\[(]*([0-9;])[@-n]/}"
  done
}
```

See:

1. [linuxjournal.com: Extended Globbing](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing)
2. [gnu.org: Bash Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: This doesn’t work. Test with `tldr`. (Though I use zsh so it might also be because of that.)

Comment: Indeed, Zsh will not understand Bash’s extended globing `extglob` or probably neither will it understand string replacement altogether.

Comment: I did enable the extendedglob of zsh ... String replacement should be posix, too?

Comment: String replacement is not POSIX. You can use any of the alternate methods using `sed` mentioned here that will work with Zsh.

Comment: This solution has the advantage of line-buffering the text. I tried with sed but it was block-buffering my pipe.

Comment: The fundamental idea here, doing simply string replacements, worked well for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210909/565877 I had very specific codes to remove (red, green, stop color), and I have an ugly 6-8 lines removing each color code. I'm sure this could be a fine solution for some use cases, if you made the regex simpler. (Probably the `$'\e'` bit is particularly problematic?)

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem. All solutions I found did work well for the color codes but did not remove the characters added by `"$(tput sgr0)"` (resetting attributes).

Taking, for example, the solution in the [comment by davemyron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998978/removing-colors-from-output#comment76844503_18000433) the length of the resulting string in the example below is 9, not 6:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

string="$(tput setaf 9)foobar$(tput sgr0)"
string_sed="$( sed -r "s/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]//g" <<< "${string}" )"
echo ${#string_sed}
```

In order to work properly, the regex had to be extend to also match the sequence added by `sgr0` ("`\E(B`"):

```
string_sed="$( sed -r "s/\x1B(\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]|\(B)//g" <<< "${string}" )"
```

Comment: @Jarodiv - thanks for the most comprehansive approach. All the answers provided on this topic deal ONLY with ANSI/VT100 Control sequences (ex: "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"), however do not remediate anything caused by TPUT text formatting (ex: tput smso/tput setaf X/tput rmso/tput sgr0). As a result after all   'sed' executions there was some other mess remaining in the logs. This is a pure solution to my usecases!

Answer (score 8):

Not sure what's in `./somescript` but if escape sequences are not hardcoded you can set the terminal type to avoid them

```
TERM=dumb ./somescript
```

For example, if you try

```
TERM=dumb tput sgr0 | xxd
```

you'll see it produces no output while

```
tput sgr0 | xxd
00000000: 1b28 421b 5b6d                           .(B.[m
```

does (for xterm-256color).

Comment: Simplest solution/answer by far!

Comment: Assuming your tools pay attention to the terminal type. In general, well behaved tools already have a switch to disable ANSI sequences (usually badly named like `--no-color`)

Comment: @sehe that's why I mentioned "but if escape sequences are not hardcoded..."

Comment: I upvoted, but in the general case this is not easy to tell. I suppose it will be a minority of tools that use `tput`, and a somehwat wider set of tools that tries to be smart (or even sometimes correct) about terminal capabilities.

Comment: `TERM=dumb` folks

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure Bash solution.

Save as `strip-escape-codes.sh`, make executable and then run `<command-producing-colorful-output> | ./strip-escape-codes.sh`.

Note that this strips **all** ANSI escape codes/sequences. If you want to strip colors only, replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `"m"`.

Bash >= 4.0:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Strip ANSI escape codes/sequences [$1: input string, $2: target variable]
function strip_escape_codes() {
    local _input="$1" _i _char _escape=0
    local -n _output="$2"; _output=""
    for (( _i=0; _i < ${#_input}; _i++ )); do
        _char="${_input:_i:1}"
        if (( ${_escape} == 1 )); then
            if [[ "${_char}" == [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
                _escape=0
            fi
            continue
        fi
        if [[ "${_char}" == $'\e' ]]; then
            _escape=1
            continue
        fi
        _output+="${_char}"
    done
}

while read -r line; do
    strip_escape_codes "${line}" line_stripped
    echo "${line_stripped}"
done
```

Bash < 4.0:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Strip ANSI escape codes/sequences [$1: input string, $2: target variable]
function strip_escape_codes() {
    local input="${1//\"/\\\"}" output="" i char escape=0
    for (( i=0; i < ${#input}; ++i )); do         # process all characters of input string
        char="${input:i:1}"                       # get current character from input string
        if (( ${escape} == 1 )); then             # if we're currently within an escape sequence, check if
            if [[ "${char}" == [a-zA-Z] ]]; then  # end is reached, i.e. if current character is a letter
                escape=0                          # end reached, we're no longer within an escape sequence
            fi
            continue                              # skip current character, i.e. do not add to ouput
        fi
        if [[ "${char}" == $'\e' ]]; then         # if current character is '\e', we've reached the start
            escape=1                              # of an escape sequence -> set flag
            continue                              # skip current character, i.e. do not add to ouput
        fi
        output+="${char}"                         # add current character to output
    done
    eval "$2=\"${output}\""                       # assign output to target variable
}

while read -r line; do
    strip_escape_codes "${line}" line_stripped
    echo "${line_stripped}"
done
```

Comment: Well, this solution could be even less complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, not sure if this will work for you, but 'tr' will 'strip' (delete) **control codes** - try:

```
./somescript | tr -d '[:cntrl:]'
```

Comment: Suddenly it's also remove new lines

Comment: Yes, LF and CR (codes) are control codes;  if your are interested in more than one line then this may not be a solution.  Since it appears that you are running a JAVA program I will guess that the colors are managed from there;  Otherwise you would need to look at your console setup (i.e. terminal settings/color scheme) and/or at the options for each command that supports 'colors', i.e. ls --color=never

Comment: I like this answer for its elegance, even if it does more than just removing colours. Thanks!

Comment: it actually let codes there, see ls -l + your command: `rwxr-xr-x 1 tokra admin 22 Oct 18 14:21 [0m[01;36m/usr/local/opt/gradle[0m -> [01;34m../Cellar/gradle/4.2.1[0m/`

Comment: Control codes are not ANSI codes. This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Hmm... You are correct - my response did not directly answer the question - about removing colors.  Also, seems that we have read different documents on ANSI  codes - the ones I have read include 'control codes' as part of the standards (there are many...) :)

Answer (score 3):

@jeff-bowman's solution helped me getting rid of SOME of the color codes. 
I added another small portion to the regex in order to remove some more:

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" # Original. Removed Red ([31;40m[1m[error][0m)
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9];)?([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" # With an addition, removed yellow and green ([1;33;40m[1m[warning][0m and [1;32;40m[1m[ok][0m)
                ^^^^^^^^^
                remove Yellow and Green (and maybe more colors)
```

Answer (score 3):

The controversial idea would be to reconfigure terminal settings for this process environment to let the process know that terminal does not support colors.

Something like `TERM=xterm-mono ./somescript` comes to my mind. YMMV with your specific OS and ability of your script to understand terminal color settings.

Comment: I used your solution and it worked. However, I believe you may need to set if to something other than `xterm*`, at least it didn't work for me until I set `TERM` to anything that didn't start with `xterm`.

In my case: `TERM= ./my_script` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I had some issues with colorized output which the other solutions here didn't process correctly, so I built this perl one liner. It looks for escape `\e` followed by opening bracket `\[` followed by one or color codes `\d+` separated by semicolons, ending on `m`.

```sh
perl -ple 's/\e\[\d+(;\d+)*m//g'
```

It seems to work really well for colorized compiler output.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers didn't quite manage to strip *all* escape codes (e.g. `\x1b[?25l`).

This little sed command should do the trick:

```bash
./somescript | sed -r 's/[\x1B\x9B][][()#;?]*(([a-zA-Z0-9;]*\x07)|([0-9;]*[0-9A-PRZcf-ntqry=><~]))//g'
```

The regex is a modification of https://github.com/acarl005/stripansi/blob/master/stripansi.go#L7

Answer (score 1):

I spent little bit searching around for a solution that didn't involve memorizing sed spells, and have not seen this suggested anywhere:

`./somescript | tr -dc '[[:print:][:space:]]'`

removes any character that is not either printable or whitespace (including vertical).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question/answers trying to do something similar as the OP.  I found some other useful resources and came up with a log script based on those.  Posting here in case it can help others.

Digging into the links helps understand some of the redirection which I won't try and explain because I'm just starting to understand it myself.

Usage will render the colorized output to the console, while stripping the color codes out of the text going to the log file. It will also include stderr in the logfile for any commands that don't work.

Edit: adding more usage at bottom to show how to log in different ways

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

. $DIR/dev.conf
. $DIR/colors.cfg

filename=$(basename ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})
# remove extension
# filename=`echo $filename | grep -oP '.*?(?=\.)'`
filename=`echo $filename | awk -F\. '{print $1}'`
log=$DIR/logs/$filename-$target

if [ -f $log ]; then
  cp $log "$log.bak"
fi

exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>$log 2>&1


# log message
log(){
    local m="$@"
    echo -e "*** ${m} ***" >&3
    echo "=================================================================================" >&3
  local r="$@"
    echo "================================================================================="
    echo -e "*** $r ***" | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g"
    echo "================================================================================="
}

echo "=================================================================================" >&3
log "${Cyan}The ${Yellow}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME} ${filename} ${Cyan}script has been executed${NC}"
log $(ls) #log $(<command>)

log "${Green}Apply tag to image $source with version $version${NC}"
# log $(exec docker tag $source $target 3>&2) #prints error only to console
# log $(docker tag $source $target 2>&1) #prints error to both but doesn't exit on fail
log $(docker tag $source $target 2>&1) && exit $? #prints error to both AND exits on fail
# docker tag $source $target 2>&1 | tee $log # prints gibberish to log
echo $? # prints 0 because log function was successful
log "${Purple}Push $target to acr${NC}"
```

Here are the other links that helped:

- [Can I use sed to manipulate a variable in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744006/can-i-use-sed-to-manipulate-a-variable-in-bash)
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42728/what-does-31-12-23-do-in-a-script
- https://serverfault.com/questions/103501/how-can-i-fully-log-all-bash-scripts-actions
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections

Answer (score 0):

I used perl as I have to do this frequently on many files. This will go through all files with filename*.txt and will remove any formatting. This works for my use case and may be useful for someone else too so just thought of posting here. replace whatever your file name is in place of filename*.txt or you can put file names separated by spaces in setting the FILENAME variable below.

```
$ FILENAME=$(ls filename*.txt) ; for file in $(echo $FILENAME); do echo $file; cat $file | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b > $file-new; mv $file-new $file; done
```

Answer (score 0):

my contribution:

```
./somescript | sed -r "s/\\x1B[\\x5d\[]([0-9]{1,3}(;[0-9]{1,3})?(;[0-9]{1,3})?)?[mGK]?//g"
```

Answer (score -3):

for macOS

```
$ my_program | pbcopy && pbpaste
```

Comment: What makes you think that `pbcopy` removes escape sequences for colour codes from the input?

Answer (score -8):

This works for me:

```
./somescript | cat
```

Comment: That depends on how `somescript` is implemented.  It may or may not recognise that its standard output is a tty.  (The words offenders actually hard-code terminal-specific escape codes into the program, and break horribly when used on other terminals or in scripts).

Comment: Thanks Toby. I used django's manage.py to test, but what you said makes sense.