# Ansible: remove unwanted characters in stdout

Tags: ansible

I am running an ansible play where I want to parse the output of the `kubect cluser-info` command.

What I expected to get is:

```
    $ kubectl cluster-info
    Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.60.11:6443
    KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.60.11:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

    To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

What I am actually getting from the following tasks:

```
    - name: master_setup.yml --> Check if cluster is already running and exit if so
      shell: "kubectl cluster-info"
      failed_when: false
      register: rv_cluster_info
      environment:
        KUBECONFIG: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
      become: yes


    - name: master_setup.yml --> DEBUG
      debug:
        var: rv_cluster_info
```

is this:

```
ok: [kubernetes-master-1] => 
  rv_cluster_info:
    changed: true
    cmd: kubectl cluster-info
    delta: '0:00:00.174232'
    end: '2019-04-07 09:41:39.237907'
    failed: false
    failed_when_result: false
    rc: 0
    start: '2019-04-07 09:41:39.063675'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: |-
      [0;32mKubernetes master[0m is running at [0;33mhttps://192.168.60.11:6443[0m
      [0;32mKubeDNS[0m is running at [0;33mhttps://192.168.60.11:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy[0m

      To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
    stdout_lines:
    - "\e[0;32mKubernetes master\e[0m is running at \e[0;33mhttps://192.168.60.11:6443\e[0m"
    - "\e[0;32mKubeDNS\e[0m is running at \e[0;33mhttps://192.168.60.11:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy\e[0m"
    - ''
    - To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

How can I get rid of this irritating `\e[0;33` stuff?

**edit**: Apparently these are color codes printed by `kubectl` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick

```
- name: master_setup.yml --> DEBUG REGEX
  debug:
    var: rv_cluster_info.stdout | regex_replace('\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]', '')
```

regex used from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18000433/2409793) SO answer.