# Get Gitlab CI coverage with flow coverage report

Tags: gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci, flowtype

I'm using [flow-coverage-report](https://github.com/rpl/flow-coverage-report) to get the coverage rate of my code by Flow. I've added a job in my Gitlab CI pipeline to execute it and retrieve the coverage rate.

```
jobName:
  stage: stage
  script:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/flow-coverage-report
  coverage: /MyProject\s*│\s*([\d\.]+)/
```

The output of the script is a lot of lines and more particularly :

```
┌───────────┬─────────┬───────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ project   │ percent │ total │ covered │ uncovered │
│ MyProject │    87 % │ 62525 │   54996 │      7529 │
└───────────┴─────────┴───────┴─────────┴───────────┘
```

*They are not using the pipe character | for the table, but │*

When I debug the regex with [Rubular](https://rubular.com/) as explained in the [GitLab Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-parsing), I get the right result in the matching group.

However, every time my job finishes, it does not have any coverage value. Am I missing something ? Are the characters displayed differently ?

**Note** : I have no problems with Jest coverage for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after digging in the code and other places, I've found the culprit => colors in the output.

The first line of the table above was actually displayed in green !

So to have the correct value interpreted by the GitLab regex, one can include the colors in the regex or just strip the colors like I did :

```
./node_modules/.bin/flow-coverage-report | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g"
```

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18000433/1259118).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've run into this before as well