# BASH - Is there a way to save output of a command to a file with the source formatting?

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

So to put it less confusing:

I run a command which prints some formatted values in the bash e.g.:

- NodeID   (lot of whitespace)   Heap_size     (again)     Time

And when i try to save the output with `Name:~$ script > file.txt`, the output is:

```
ESC[93mnode_s1aESC[0m^MESC[25C1.0g
```

Expected output:

```
node_s1a            1.0g       ...
node_s2aaaaa        2.0g       ...
```

Is there a way to save raw output with the formatting into a text file ?

Comment: That is a bug with the program producing the output, as it is writing terminal control characters when it is not writing to a terminal.  Perhaps the command you are using has an option to suppress that behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998978/removing-colors-from-output

Comment: Thanks both, one is a cause and the second is at least partly solution, so i think this topic can be closed.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `printf` command which is like the printf function in C or Java.

```
printf "%-20s%s" Name:~$ script >> test.txt
```

I'm assuming `Name:~$` and `script` are variables because I've never seen them before.

Comment: `Name:~$`is the Bash prompt and `script` is the name of the script they are running. Probably stay away from topics you are clearly not familiar with.