# How to remove color from color terminal text in python

Tags: python, terminal

I have one string that is color terminal text (bash), now I'd like to display it as plain text via removing the color, is there any way or library to do that? Here's one example color text:

```
[1m[34mpeopleSchema[0m: [1m[32morg.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType[0m = StructType(StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true))
[1m[34mdf[0m: [1m[32morg.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame[0m = [id: int, name: string]
[1m[34mres1[0m: [1m[32morg.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame[0m = []
```

Comment: The issue is related to which the terminal is, cmd, PowerShell, bash.....?

Comment: The terminal is bash

Comment: you just want to disable the rendering of color ANSI codes or remove them from the string? For later check https://stackoverflow.com/q/14693701/4046632

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove them with regular expressions, i.e.

```
import re

dirty = '''[1m[34mpeopleSchema[0m: [1m[32morg.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType[0m = StructType(StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true))
[1m[34mdf[0m: [1m[32morg.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame[0m = [id: int, name: string]
[1m[34mres1[0m: [1m[32morg.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame[0m = []'''

cleaned = re.sub('\[[0-9;]+[a-zA-Z]',' ',dirty)
print(cleaned)
```

But it may sometimes remove more than necessary. See also discussion of:
[Removing colors from output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998978/removing-colors-from-output)

It would be more reliable to disable terminal coloring, but sometimes it is not the option.